# How to design an accordion menu, for mobile, where the expander elements are also links

Tags: css, touch, accordion, expand

I have a Mobile design to fulfil:

[image: Accordion Menu]

The menu is a fairly standard Accordion setup.

- It starts collapsed.
- Tapping *anywhere* on `A` will expand it to show the `A` sub-menu.
- Tapping *anywhere* on `B` will collapse `A` and expand `B`.
- Tapping *anywhere* on `A Sub 1` will take you to that link.

All standard so far! But the additional Feature is that `A` is itself a page that the user might want to access!
We have to fulfil this very specific design, so we can't add expander controls, to separate the link from the expand.

I was originally using simple nested `<ul>` lists and some trivial JS to bind into the onclick events. That was fine for elements that were links OR expanders but that fell apart on bits that were both.

I tried changing the behaviour to exposes the submenu on hover, to utilise the behaviour that I discovered, and documented here: [Tablets hover on first click, click on second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353912/tablets-hover-on-first-click-click-on-second-click)
That does technically work, but not very well: you can't scroll the menu properly because touching outside your current expansion will change the selection; the hover exposure of the submenu isn't animated; it generally doesn't actually work well for phones and on a small desktop screen it's completely unusable.

I've looked for ages online for an example or a library that will Just Do This, but nothing fits what I need, and we've been given this very specific design spec.

Currently my only solution is going to be to implement the 2 phase clicking myself in javascript, storing the current state of the element in data attributes and reading those before deciding what action to take on click.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

See here for SO posts about related scenarios for a traditional navbar menu:

- [Tablets hover on first click, click on second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353912/tablets-hover-on-first-click-click-on-second-click)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354150/deactivate-hover-on-tablet

Answer (score -3):

You just need sit at your computer and watch for responses in about 50 years when all programs will include multiple touch, voice recognition, and thought features to accommodate your functionality request.

Personal experience dictates this problem will not be solved in less then 5 to ten years based on Moore's Law and general apathy on the internet.

Comment: This sounds like more of a comment than an answer. Please delete this answer and move it to the comment section.

Comment: Ditto. This is not adding anything to the discussion (or any future discussion).